# Save the printed message of a function, which is printed in the console, into a string

Tags: c, string, console

Consider that there is a function named `Func` written in C language. `Func` prints a string in the `console` by using `printf` command.

What is important is I don't have access to the implementation of `Func`.

> Question: How I can save the printed message of `Func` in a string?

Comment: [Rerouting stdin and stdout from C](//stackoverflow.com/q/584868)

Comment: I think there is a sprintf() in C

Comment: Do you want to capture all messages written to standard output or just those written by `Func()`?  What about functions called by `Func()`?  If it is only `Func()` and what it calls, then without the implementation, it will be very hard to do anything, especially for indirect calls to `Func()`.  Hard verging on impossible, though it depends on how platform-specific you’re willing to go. Any such technique will be very fiddly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I want to capture all messages written to standard output.

Comment: Are you working on a POSIX platform, such as Linux or macOS, or are you working on a Windows platform?  The answer will be different for the two cases.  You've said you want to capture "all messages written to standard output" — does that mean "including those written by other functions unrelated to `Func()`, or only those created by `Func()` and the functions it calls?"  When are you going to need to access the string?  How do you plan to access it?  How much data are you likely to be capturing in the worst case (will it ever be more than 64 KiB)? _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_  Is it OK if reading the string destroys the saved data?  Will you ever need to read the data multiple times? — There's a lot of unstated information missing!  Under a POSIX system, assuming you are only interesting in capturing what `Func()` writes to standard output, you'll need to use a wrapper around calls to it — and it will be fairly heavyweight.  It will flush standard output before calling `Func()`, arrange to redirect standard output temporarily to a file, call the function, flush standard output again when it returns, unredirect the standard output, _[…continued…]_

Comment: _[…continuation…]_ and then you have to decide how to expose what's in the file as a string — what is the interface to that?  I assume equivalent facilities are available under Windows, but don't know the details of the Windows API.